# Avoiding media embedded in div to get refreshed on addition by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, socket.io-1.0

I am building a chat web app using socket.io and node.I am adding user's chat in a div using innerHTML.But the problem is that when a new message is added to the chat container(div block),the previous media present in chat-container reloads every time a new chat is added.I want to avoid this.Can anyone help me to find a solution for this?I would love to hear your ideas.
Here is the abstract code i am using

```
HTML
```

```
<input type = "text" id = "message" placeholder="Type something..." /><i onclick = "sendMessage()" style="color:green;" title="Send" id="sendbtn"></i>
```

i am not using input in form element

clientJS:

```
function sendMessage(){
   var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;
   if (msg) {
      postFile({message: msg,id:id, user: user, color: color,roomid:nativeRoom});
      socket.emit("msg", { message: msg,id:id, user: user, color: color,roomid:nativeRoom});             
   }
}
socket.on("newmsg",function(data){
   postFile(data);
   //Actually postFile is here because it can include video,audio as well
});
function postFile(data){
//here i want to prevent message-container div from reloading its previous media(i have ignored most of the css code to make it precise)
   document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += '<div class="messages '+data.user+'chatpiece" id="'+data.id+'"><div><div><b>'+data.user+'</b><img src="'+userprofileimagelink+'"/></div><span>' +{time_when_message_posted} +'</span></div><hr><span style="max-width:100%;word-wrap:break-word;font-size:1.1em;" class="messagemain">' +data.message+"</span></div>"; 
}
```

server-side:

```
socket.on('msg',function(data){
  socket.broadcast.to(data.roomid).emit('newmsg',data);
});
```

I want to avoid reload of video and audio media present in chat container when a new message will be added.
How may i achieve this?

Comment: @Lonnie Best Yeah!It worked...i used jquery append() method instead(so to avoid adding subsequent child separately) and it worked...thank you so much for your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead of modifying the `.innerHTML` each time. Once a web page renders html, it becomes DOM. Append to the DOM instead of "converting DOM back into html via `innerHTML` each time and then appending additional HTML strings to that conversion" (like you're doing). Learn about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) if you don't know it.